Closing port is not working effectively in pyqt app
I run this function on a buttton click. When I try closing the port I do not get any error, but by trying to connect to port one more time, I get this erro "Cannot configure port, something went wrong. Original message: PermissionError(13, 'A device attached to the system is not functioning.', None, 31)".
def On_Connect_Click(Gui):
  if(Gui.connect_btn.text() == "Disconnect"):
    Gui.connect_btn.setText("Connect")
    Gui.connect_btn.setStyleSheet("background-color: #FFD700; ")
    Gui.write_thread.stop()
    Gui.read_thread.stop()
    time.sleep(0.1)  # Small delay to ensure buffers are cleared
    Gui.ser.close()
    del Gui.ser  # Remove the serial object completely
  else: # (self.connect_bt.text() == "Connect")
    try:
        # Set up serial connection
        Gui.ser = serial.Serial(Gui.port_combo.currentText(),
                            Gui.baud_combo.currentText(),
                            timeout=1,
                            bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
                            stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
                            parity=serial.PARITY_NONE)
        Gui.ser.read_buffer_size = 4096
    except Exception as e :
        print("Failed")
        print(e)
        Gui.show_message("Connection failed. Check the Port number.", title="Connection Failed")
        return
    # write_thread includes Writing myltiple Regs command and Read_req command
    Start_read_write_threads(Gui)

    Gui.connect_btn.setText("Disconnect")
    Gui.connect_btn.setStyleSheet("background-color: Red; color: white;")
    time.sleep(1)  #If you delete this, UI will be closed.

Also, closing whole application does not close the port. After reopening the app I still can't connect to the port. unless I unplug and plug the USB manually.

Maybe moving Gui.ser to a separate global variable could fix the issue.

you asked "Why are you starting the thread after you have closed the serial port ?"
But, I am not doing such thing.

You are correct, i understood the logic incorrectly first. By any change, what OS are you running this?
